# ECKS-PS algorithm: searching in encrypted data; bilinear maps

Tags: cryptography

I have found an encryption algorithm named ECKS-PS (published in a paper named 'efficient conjunctive keyword search on encrypted data storage system', written by Jin Wook Byun, Dong Hoon Lee, and Jong In Lim) that allows an user to search in encrypted data. 
The algorithm is described here: img210.imageshack.us/img210/4644/eckps.png (I have written out the steps a little bit more clear here:  img801.imageshack.us/img801/3373/stepsecksps.jpg)

I have tried multiple times to use the algorithm to search for an encrypted word, but I never get a match between the left part of the equation and the right part of the equation. (see calculations: http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/474/firstpagecalculations.jpg and http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/8712/secondpagecalculations.jpg)

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and/or provide me with an example where you get a match (based on the ECKS-PS algorithm). I know there may be other algorithms to search in encrypted data but I would like to know how to do it with this algorithm.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may misunderstand the calculation of pairing. Assume that e(g, g)= 53, and H(w) be g^2 or g^3 then you can apply bilinearity to those formulas.

For more information, see [Miller's algorithm](http://crypto.stanford.edu/miller/). It is somewhat difficult though.

Or you can try [PBC Libaray](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) which wraps pairing calculation very well. You can verify the algorithm by using it.